# Python: check if coordinates of values in a grid connect to one another

Tags: python, coordinates

Imagine I have a grid like this:

```
XXXOO
XXOOX
XXOXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

Which represents a 5x5 grid. The O's have the following coordinates.

```
dict = {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}
```

The O's hang together, so if this grid all the O's "stick" together it should output True.

Following grid the O's don't stick together and should output False

```
XXXOO
XXOXO
XXOXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

with following coordinates:

```
dict = {(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}
```

Here you obviously notice the 2nd row, 3th column and 3th row 3th column aren't connected.

I'm trying out to configure a function that takes care of it, with as input a dictionary, list, tuple...

This is what I have so far the first function just translates my characters/numbers into coordinates. The second function is what I tried so far, but just fails.o I tried to count until a total of 5 if total = 5 (so 5 are connected) it should output True. What I have so far is it always outputs True... which is obvious if you go step by step through the code. But I have no clue how to check if the coords are connected. Taken in mind the coordinates can be given quite random, not from 1-2-3-4-5 but from 4-1-2-5-3

```
def groups(grid):

    groups = {}
    row = 1;

    for row in range(len(grid)):
        # Make coordinates
        #print("R: " + str(row))
        for column in range(len(grid[row])):
            #print("C: " + str(column))
            number = grid[row][column]
            if char in groups:
                groups[char].add((row,column))
            else:
                groups.update({char:{(row,column)}})

    return groups

def connected(group):
    total = 0;
    for position in groep:
        for position2 in groep:
            if not position == position2:
                if position[0] in position2:
                    total += 1
                    print(total)

    if total == 5:
        connected = True
    else:
        connected = False

    return connected
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you have to do double DFS here.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name - it shadows the builtin. It's even worse when the variable `dict` is a `set`.

Comment: Are there always 5 Os?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using DFS of the graph and a memory of visited nodes:

```
from random import choice

def test_if_connected(points):
    def neighbours((x, y)):
        candidates = [(x - 1, y), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x, y + 1)]
        return [c for c in candidates if c in points]

    seen = set()

    # Pick any circle on the grid to start
    frontier = [choice(list(points))]

    while not len(frontier) == 0:
        # Pop the frontier for DFS
        element = frontier.pop()

        # Remember seeing the element to avoid cycles
        seen.add(element)

        # Add unseen neighbours to the search frontier
        frontier.extend([n for n in neighbours(element) if not n in seen])

    # Circles are connected if algorithm terminates having seen all
    return len(seen) == len(points)

# Points represented by circles
connected_points    = set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)])
disconnected_points = set([(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)])

print test_if_connected(connected_points) # => True
print test_if_connected(disconnected_points) # => False
```

It should be clear from the commented code how the answer is achieved, you may wish to become familiar how a depth-first/breadth-first search works elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the label connected components function in skimage. If more than 1 number of components found, not all the O's are connected.

```
from skimage import morphology
import numpy as np

def connected(grid_size, O):
    grid = np.zeros((grid_size,grid_size))
    for i,j in O:
        grid[i,j] = 1
    numlabels = np.max(morphology.label(grid,4))
    if numlabels == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


Os = {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}
Os2 =  {(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}

print connected(5,Os)
print connected(5,Os2)
```

Output

```
True
False
```

docs for reference: 
http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.8.0/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.label

Comment: Actually, skimage's implementation is way faster, use that :)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a "flood fill" function which check each O and call itself recursively if there is an O above, below or an O to the left or right of the current O. You need to make sure you don't recheck O's that you have already checked or you will end up in an endless loop.

When your function returns (from the recursive loop) you may check if there are any unchecked O's left. If so they are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why your code seems so complex when it need to be, Utilizing List-comprehensions and the `enumerate()` function It didn't seem that complex to find the coordinates of `O`.

Try this instead:

```
grid = """
XXXOO
XXOOX
XXOXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
"""
def groups(grid):
    group_lst = [i for i in grid.split('\n') if i]

    coordinates = []
    for row,column in enumerate(group_lst):
        occurences = [i for i,k in enumerate(column) if k is 'O']
        coordinates.append([(row,i) for i in occurences])
    return [k for i in coordinates for k in i]

print groups(grid)
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Nice iterative approach to this. Will this work in the general case?

Comment: The questioner doesn't want to find the coordinates of the `O`s, he wants to determine whether all the `O`s are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for the answers! I don't know skimage and all packages yet... still learning with the basics. My full solution became this, based on a lot of comments here.

First function finds coordinates from given grid as a list
Second function finds the connected item
Third function checks every item in the grid and checks if each character has the same number of occurrences inside the grid.

```
def groepen(rooster):

    groepen = {}
    rij = 1;

    for rij in range(len(rooster)):
        # Coordinaten bepalen
        #print("R: " + str(rij))
        for kolom in range(len(rooster[rij])):
            #print("K: " + str(kolom))
            getal = rooster[rij][kolom]
            if getal in groepen:
                groepen[getal].add((rij,kolom))
            else:
                groepen.update({getal:{(rij,kolom)}})

    return groepen

def samenhangend(groep):
    # Controle variabele
    samenhangend = False

    # originele_coord en rooster een set maken: moet unieke waarden bevatten
    originele_coord = set()
    rooster = set()
    # Lijst maken van de coordinaten die worden meegegeven aan de functie
    coordinaten = list(groep)
    # Eerste coordinaat toevoegen aan het rooster
    rooster.add(coordinaten[0])

    # Lus lopen zolang er coordinaten zitten in het rooster
    while rooster:
        # coordinaat uithalen uit het rooster
        coordinaat = rooster.pop()
        # coordinaat toevoegen in aanliggend
        originele_coord.add(coordinaat)

        # variabelen x en y aanmaken voor coordinaten
        (x,y) = coordinaat

        # Lijst van de mogelijke buren per coordinaat
        aanliggende_coord = [(x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1)]

        # Lus voor ieder coordinaat van de aanliggende coordinaten
        for coord in aanliggende_coord:
            # Controle als het coordinaat nog niet in de set originele_coord zit, en als het terug te vinden is in de 
            # coordinaten, als het er nog niet inzit maar wel in de coordinaten het toevoegen aan het rooster. 
            if not coord in originele_coord and coord in coordinaten:
                rooster.add(coord)

    # Als er evenveel coordinaten zijn als aanliggende dan is het een correcte evendeling.
    if len(originele_coord) == len(groep):
        samenhangend = True

    return samenhangend

def evendeling(rooster):
    # Standaard variabele evendeling
    evendeling = True
    # Variabele voor de lus de tellen
    teller = 0

    # Coordinaten getallen bepalen van het meegegeven rooster
    rooster_coord = groepen(rooster)


    # Voor iedere coordinaten set in het rooster, controleren als deze samenhangend zijn of niet
    for coord_set in rooster_coord:
        #print(evendeling)
        # Lengte controleren , als het aantal coordinaten niet hetzelfde is al de vorige klopt het ook niet
        if teller == 0:
            lengte_coord = len(rooster_coord[coord_set])
        if not lengte_coord == len(rooster_coord[coord_set]):
            evendeling = False
        teller += 1

        # Als het niet samenhangend is dan zetten we evendeling op False
        if samenhangend(rooster_coord[coord_set]) == False:
            evendeling = False

    return evendeling

rooster = [[1, 1, 1, 5, 5], [2, 1, 5, 5, 4], [2, 1, 5, 4, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4, 3], [2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
evendeling(rooster)

rooster = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3]]
print(groepen(rooster))

print(evendeling([['K', 'V', 'V'], ['K', 'K', 'V'], ['q', 'q', 'q']])) # Should be TRUE!
```